# How do i set more than 1 value if a condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas

i wonder if its possible to set 3 values if condition is met: for exemple i have a `10000` row file in excel , and i want to try a code to automate this process because i can't do it manually , i have a lot of blank cells in column Rate and i want to fill it with a predefined rates between (`0%,0-20%,20-40%,40-60%`)

```
Company         Interest     Rate
X1        not interested     0%
X2        interested         0-20%
X3        interested         20-40%
X4        interested         40-60%
X5        not interested     0%
X6        interested         
X7        interested         
X8        interested
```

So i want to apply a if condition where the rate of companies interested is between these three options (`0-20%,20-40%,40-60%`) to fill the Rate column

**What i've tried ?**

so its more like this function if its existed :

```
df.loc[df['Interest'] == 'interested', 'Rate'] ="0-20%" OR "40-60%" OR "20-40%"
```

**Desired Results**

```
Company         Interest     Rate
X1        not interested     0%
X2        interested         0-20%
X3        interested         20-40%
X4        interested         40-60%
X5        not interested     0%
X6        interested         0-20%   
X7        interested         40-60%
X8        interested         20-40%
```

Comment: How do you choose the values for the Rate column? Just rotate through them? It would be trivial to do  that in Excel, why do you want to do it in Python?

Comment: just randomly it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `random.choice` for that.

edited my answer like in the comments asked.

```
import random

rndm = ["0-20%", "40-60%", "20-40%"]
df['Rate'] = df['Rate'].fillna(value=-1)
df['Rate'] = [random.choice(rndm) if (x=='interested' and y==-1) else '0%' if x=='not interested' else y for x,y in zip(df['Interest'],df['Rate'])]
```

Here is the other (and better) solution modified for your purpose of only filling part of the column:

```
rndm = ["0-20%", "40-60%", "20-40%"]
df['Rate'] = df['Rate'].fillna(value=-1)
df['Rate'] = df.apply(lambda x: random.choice(rndm) if (x['Interest'] == 'interested' and x['Rate']==-1) else x['Rate'], axis=1)
```

I just was curious which solution is faster and did a little test. Actually my solution with `list comprehension` is much faster than with `apply`, ...in case performance matters.

```
rndm = ["0-20%", "40-60%", "20-40%"]
dic = {'Company': ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7', 'X8'],
 'Interest': ['not interested', 'interested', 'interested', 'interested', 'not interested', 'interested', 'interested', 'interested'],
 'Rate': ['0%', '0-20%', '20-40%', '40-60%', '0%', None, None, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

def with_list_comprehension():
    res = [random.choice(rndm) if (x=='interested' and y==-1) else '0%' if x=='not interested' else y for x,y in zip(df['Interest'],df['Rate'])]
    return res

def with_apply():
    res = df.apply(lambda x: random.choice(rndm) if (x['Interest'] == 'interested' and x['Rate']==-1) else x['Rate'], axis=1)
    return res

%timeit -n 10000 with_list_comprehension()
21.5 µs ± 2.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit -n 10000 with_apply()
1.13 ms ± 78.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: @Hercules edited my answer again with a little time comparison

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function to alter existing dataframe.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Interest' : ['interested','interested','interested']})
df['Rate'] = "dummy"

df.Rate = df.apply(lambda x: random.choice(["0-20%", "40-60%", "20-40%"]) if x.Interest == 'interested' else x.Rate, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Comment: also i have another question , can i modify the blank cells only cuz it will change the existing Interested  rates

Comment: you mean you want like in your first example only fill the lines X6 to X8 because the others are already modified ?

Comment: @Hercules Yes, Just use an **and** condition `if x.Interest == 'interested' and x.Rate != ''`. Not sure what value you have used for empty. But ideally, I would suggest using df.fillna() to have a singular value for nulls. Try `numpy.nan`

Comment: Exactly @Rabinzel that's what i meant

Comment: I'll modify my answer but I guess if you have to check conditions in multiple columns, the solution here from @High-Octane with `apply` is the better solution.